# Scopes in a class in Python

Tags: python, scope, function

Please have a look at this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, bid_code):
        self.__bid = bid_code

    def doit(self, cry):
        self.bid_it = cry

    def show_bid(self):
        print self.__bid

    def show_it(self):
        print self.bid_it

a = Car("ok")
a.show_bid()
a.doit("good")
a.show_it()
```

What is the scope of `bid_it` here? I thought it was a local variable, because it is inside a `def` block. How is it possible that I can call it outside the function? I haven't declared that `bid_it` is global.

Thanks

Comment: The only time the *variable* `bid_code` is used is in the constructor, where it is the parameter. In all other case the *property* is accessed. Properties are not "scoped" as variables, although they run through a resolution chain. Neither properties nor variables are objects -- they can only contain/refer to objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `self`, you've bound it to the instance. It's now an instance variable. Instance variables are local to their instances. If the variable were unbound (no self prefix), it'd have function scope and go out of scope once the method call is over, but you've bound it to something else (the instance).

Comment: @steve If his answer really answered your question, you should accept it as the answer by clicking the check mark. It really helps out the community.

Answer (score 0):

```
def doit(self, cry):
    self.bid_it = cry
```

'self' acts like a this pointer in c++, in this case a reference to a Car object. If bid_it is not defined in self, it's created on the fly and assigned a value. This means that you can create it anywhere, just as long as you have a reference to your object.